# Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o10495.join. : java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: pyspark, semi-join

In Azure Synapse notebook, after running quite a number of functions, I'm trying to do a semi join of two dataframes where DF1 has one column called ID and the DF2 has five columns: ID, SID, Name, Term, Desc. Now the issue is everytime I start the session, I get this error. But when I run the code cell 5-6 times, it starts working. Not sure why it keeps happening.

df1 is a union of all distinct IDs from two other dataframes.
df2 = ogdata.select('SID', 'ID', 'Name', 'Term', 'Desc').distinct()

My Join:
df3 = df2.join(df1, ["uid"], "semi")

I've tried:
Changing it to left, different join syntax where I do df1.id = df2.id but always get the error everytime I start a session. Then when I run the cell 5-6 times, it works.

My error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-127-9d80a53> in <module>
      1 ##teaching_data_current = teaching_data_current.join(uid_agg_course_teacher, teaching_data_current.uid == uid_agg_course_teacher.uid, "semi").drop(uid_agg_course_teacher.uid)
      2 teaching_data_c = coursedata.select('SubjectID','uid').distinct()
----> 3 teaching_data_curr = teaching_data_c.join(uid_agg_course_teacher, ["uid"], "semi")
      4 #teaching_data_curr = teaching_data_c.alias("t1").join(uid_agg_course_teacher.alias("t2"), teaching_data_c.uid==uid_agg_course_teacher.uid, "semi")

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in join(self, other, on, how)
   1337                 on = self._jseq([])
   1338             assert isinstance(how, str), "how should be a string"
-> 1339             jdf = self._jdf.join(other._jdf, on, how)
   1340         return DataFrame(jdf, self.sql_ctx)
   1341 

~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1302 
   1303         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304         return_value = get_return_value(
   1305             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1306 

/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
    109     def deco(*a, **kw):
    110         try:
--> 111             return f(*a, **kw)
    112         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    113             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

~/cluster-env/env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324             value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325             if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o10428.join.
: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$findAliases$1.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1763)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$$anonfun$findAliases$1.applyOrElse(Analyzer.scala:1763)
    at scala.PartialFunction.$anonfun$runWith$1$adapted(PartialFunction.scala:145)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.collect(TraversableLike.scala:359)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.collect$(TraversableLike.scala:357)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.collect(List.scala:327)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.findAliases(Analyzer.scala:1763)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.collectConflictPlans$1(Analyzer.scala:1388)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.$anonfun$dedupRight$10(Analyzer.scala:1464)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.collectConflictPlans$1(Analyzer.scala:1464)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.$anonfun$dedupRight$10(Analyzer.scala:1464)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.collectConflictPlans$1(Analyzer.scala:1464)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.$anonfun$dedupRight$10(Analyzer.scala:1464)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap$(TraversableLike.scala:242)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.flatMap(List.scala:355)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.collectConflictPlans$1(Analyzer.scala:1464)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.Analyzer$ResolveReferences$.$anonfun$dedupRight$10(Analyzer.scala:1464)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.$anonfun$flatMap$1(TraversableLike.scala:245)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:245)
```

Comment: Hey, did you ever manage to understand what was happening and how to fix it? I'm having the same error and could use any guidance as I'm out of this ideas por possible root causes.